# FetchError: invalid json response body at .. Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, next.js

I'm using nextjs and (new to graphql) trying fetch data from wordpress with graphql endpoint
I followed this repo
`https://github.com/alexander-young/wp-next-headless`

with this tutorial

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIc6NrPsHjs`

but getting this err

> FetchError: invalid json response body at http://www.ahmedsamir.rf.gd/graphql reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

the part about the query works fine, any idea?

Comment: cross-domain problem?

Comment: but that worked in the tutorial right?

Comment: Can you post the graphql response ?

Comment: You mean this?
{
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "title": "123",
          "slug": "123"
        },
        {
          "title": "test",
          "slug": "test"
        },
        {
          "title": "Hello world!",
          "slug": "hello-world"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

Comment: I would assume that you don't have `<` in your file?

Comment: I went through a similar kind of problem: I accidentally gave a comma at the end of graphql query variables. I think it's better to debug in console > Network. It's a conflict response that is coming back so the response should be stringified.

Comment: where do you think i missed `<`?

Comment: I'm doing as exactly this repo, i'm just editing the endpoint url .. is there something wrong in the repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try to hit on the valid route so that you get the JSON response.

```
 curl --request POST \
            --header 'content-type: application/json' \
            --url 'http://www.ahmedsamir.rf.gd/graphql' \
            --data '{"query":"query { __typename }"}'
```

the response you're getting HTML. that's how you get the err.

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to use this? simplify it plz

Comment: @Rafal where/ what the is route your graphql API running or fetching from? Is it local or from another server? you are trying to hit the endpoint that doesn't have a graphql server running.

Comment: okay, why did you fetch data from the website you provided? enter your local graphql server `http://localhost:4000/graphql` like that then fetch it. it will work.

Comment: I think you didn't look into the repo I provided but this endpoint is WordPress to fetch data and use it locally in the front by react

Comment: your point is valid but I look up the repo and found a local graphql server data fetching from. for your case, you fetching from a real server/website in that case you need permission (`CORS`) from the graphql server to fetch data. Because if anyone accesses your graphql server chance they will destroy your data.

Comment: please, look at this doc: https://www.wpgraphql.com/extenstion-plugins/wpgraphql-cors/

Comment: I got your point now very clear, but cause I'm new to wp and graphql, in my case where should I set cors .. cause i saw a lot of ways and idk what should I do exactly

Comment: Actually, I don't know very much about wp just a workaround to wp. There is a plugin called "WPGraphQL CORS" after installation, you go to the plugin settings and set the client URL to extended 'ACAO' header. `ref: https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-woocommerce/issues/228#issuecomment-581456822`

Comment: I did everything in ref (`https://i.ibb.co/yBt1HS1/Untitled.png`), but same issue still there

Comment: missed to tick "send site credentials" and lastly, I would say read the full docs of wpgraph cors which I provided. Make your site SSL enabled this could be the cause of all. Thank you!